Do I lack server resources when building vite application?
I'm setting up a build server for my projects using DigitalOcean droplet, Jenkins pipelines, Docker.
The most crucial stage of pipeline is bulding docker image - that's where app is actually built. The problem is, when the command vite build is run, droplet graphs show 100% CPU and memory usage and about 15 minutes later job fails with the message "ERROR: failed to solve: Canceled: context canceled". Earlier, the same thing happened on npm i, but with some help of AI, I managed to optimize it. I also tried to optimize vite build (see vite config below), but this time it didn't help.
So, my question is: do I really need bigger droplet or such behaviour can be caused by some bug or can I do something to optimize build? My droplet plan is a cheap one, with 1 vCPU and 1 GB memory. I really want to avoid paying 20$/month just for the build server that will do actual work for like 20 minutes a day.
Note: on my laptop everything is built perfectly.
pipeline log output:
#16 3.036 vite v5.4.8 building for production...
#16 3.186 transforming...
Resuming build at Tue Nov 26 09:07:43 UTC 2024 after Jenkins restart
Ready to run at Tue Nov 26 09:07:43 UTC 2024
#16 CANCELED
ERROR: failed to solve: Canceled: context canceled
wrapper script does not seem to be touching the log file in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/autopostavka-front_dev@tmp/durable-04ddde26
(JENKINS-48300: if on an extremely laggy filesystem, consider -Dorg.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.BourneShellScript.HEARTBEAT_CHECK_INTERVAL=86400)

vite.config.ts:
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import commonjs from "vite-plugin-commonjs";
import svgr from "vite-plugin-svgr";
import tsconfigPaths from "vite-tsconfig-paths";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react-swc";

export default defineConfig({
  base: "./",
  plugins: [
    react(),
    commonjs(),
    tsconfigPaths(),
    svgr({
      include: ["src/**/*.svg"],
    }),
  ],
  server: {
    open: true, // automatically open the app in the browser
    port: 3000,
  },
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      output: {
        manualChunks: {
          vendor: ['react', 'react-dom'], // Separate vendor libraries
        },
      },
    },
    minify: 'esbuild', // Alternative minifier
  },
  optimizeDeps: {
    include: ['react', 'react-dom'],
  },
  cacheDir: "./node_modules/.vite_cache",
});

Dokerfile:
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

FROM node:22.11.0-alpine3.20 AS builder
ENV NODE_VERSION=22.11.0

# Change directory so that our commands run inside this new directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy npm package files
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./

# Install npm dependencies
# Configure npm for efficiency
RUN npm set progress=false \
    && npm config set maxsockets 1 \
    && npm config set fetch-retries 5 \
    && npm config set fetch-retry-mintimeout 20000 \
    && npm config set fetch-retry-maxtimeout 60000 \
    && npm install

# Copy app files to out container
COPY . .

# Build app
RUN npm run build

### STAGE 2: Setup ###

FROM nginx:1.12-alpine

COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

# Copy build files from first image to nginx dir
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/dist/ /usr/share/nginx/html/

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]


I'm thinking about changing deployment strategy: I may build docker image locally and push it  (since my windows laptop for some reason is more capable then VM), and leave only pulling and running the container for server.
